# transferring data between my HTML page and python script

Tags: javascript, python, html, jupyter-notebook

I have a very simple HTML page for testing which has a simple dropdown menu:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select id="mySelect" onchange="copy();">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="Value of m1" >m1</option>
<option value="Value of m2" >m2</option>
<option value="Value of m3" >m3</option>
 <option value="Value of m4" >m4</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<p>The value of your selected choice is: </p>
<div id="label"></div>
function copy() 
{
    var selected_value = document.getElementById("mySelect").value
    document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = selected_value
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to transfer the value of the selection into my python script. My python script has a function which uses the passed value as an argument to give a JSON file. I want to pass the value and then run the script to produce my JSON file when I select something. This is just for testing but my final HTML page will have multiple dropdowns similar to this one each one transferring a value to my python which would be used as an argument. Everything is done locally using local host. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That's what forms are for

Comment: HTML pages and javascript are executed in the browser, your python code lives in a seperate process. Generally one would run a HTTP server and use an http request to comunicate between the website and the python server side. Common frameworks are [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [falcon](https://falconframework.org/) or many more.

Comment: There is no `form` tag with specified `action` attribute so this dropdown list value could not be submitted to the server side. Additionally, the `select` tag should has `name` attribute.

Answer (score -3):

Its a bit tricky.
You have to use a form to send the data to a PHP-Web Server.
Then use shell_exec($command) to run your Python Script with parameters.

Your PHP Script should look like this:

```
<?php
$input = $_GET['mySelect'];
//sanitize and check the input

$cmd = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py -p ' . $input);
//escape the command

$output = shell_exec($cmd);
//run the script

echo $output;
?>
```

**It's very important to sanitize and check your user input** otherwise an attacker could easily get acces to your server.

See more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Notes from php.net

> This function can return NULL both when an error occurs or the program produces >no output. It is not possible to detect execution failures using this function. >exec() should be used when access to the program exit code is required."

---

> This function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.

Comment: The question refers to `Python` and not `PHP`.

Comment: He can use PHP to run Python, there is no way to get a user input directly from the bowser.
Well he could open a socket and listen until the user sends via js some data but via php its much easier